# Grepping using shell - long delay

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a benchmark thread running and it takes a couple of hours to run.
The script for initiating  the benchmark thread was done using python. 
It prints out some random "foo" and I want to grep it for further use.

So, I wrote a shell script that does this.

```
#!/bin/bash

id = `taskset -c 0 python <path>/run-apps.py <thread> | grep "pid" | awk '{print $2}'`
echo $id
```

Since, the thread takes a very long time.
Maybe the shell script is unable to jump to the next line till the execution is over and I am unable to print the id as soon as it initiates it..

do you see any problem? or how I can rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement

```
echo $id
```

cannot run until the previous statement

```
id=`taskset -c 0 python <path>/run-apps.py <thread> | grep "pid" | awk '{print $2}'`
```

completes. If you don't need `$id`, get rid of it and simply run

```
taskset -c 0 python <path>/run-apps.py <thread> | grep "pid" | awk '{print $2}'
```

to see the output as it is generated (but you may need to disable buffering, as pointed out by Martijn). If you do need `$id`, you can use the `tee` command
to store a copy of the output and print it to standard error at the same time:

```
id=$(taskset -c 0 python <path>/run-apps.py <thread> |\
     grep "pid" | awk '{print $2}' | tee /dev/stderr) # Or some other file descriptor that goes to your terminal
```

A third option is to use a temporary file.

```
taskset -c 0 python <path>/run-apps.py <thread> | grep "pid" | awk '{print $2}' > tmpfile &
tail --pid $! -f tmpfile # Watch tmpfile until the backgrounded job completes
do-other-job --reading-from tmpfile
```

Comment: @Chepner: Thanks. so, let me make it more clear. I need to store the output to use it immediately for another tool. It is not able to store it..

Comment: It may be simpler to write the output to a temporary file than to capture it in a variable.